# how to do Api fetch and display the results

Tags: javascript

i am working on a simple app that will fetch data from an Api and display it.

a have this function

```
const getAUserProfile = () => {
  const api = 'https://randomuser.me/api/';

  // make API call here
  return fetch(api)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => displayUserPhotoAndName(response))
  notify(`requesting profile data ...`);
};
```

this is where i try to fetch the data and pass as a parameter to the displayUserPhotoAndName function.

Now in the displayUserPhotoAndName function i try to create a statement that de-structures the data parameter and obtains the results property from it;

i tried to Create a second statement in the next line that de-structures the results variable i just created, and obtain the first item from it (it is an Array! See https://randomuser.me/api/). the de-structured array item should be declared as profile. This represents the profile data for the user gotten from the API call that i want to display in my app.

this is the displayUserPhotoAndName function

```
const displayUserPhotoAndName = (data) => {
    if(!data) return;

    // add your code here
    const {results} = data;
    const {profile} = results;
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = profile[results];

    clearNotice();
  };
```

now i am trying to display the title, first name and last name with this line of code  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = profile[0].title + profile[0].first + profile[0].last;.

this is not working when i try to run it in sapio

Comment: just "it's not working" isn't very clear. I would guess - although it's very much a guess at this stage - would be that the data returned from the API isn't in the shape you're expecting. Try putting `console.log(data);` at the top of your `displayUserPhotoAndName` function, to see what kind of object you're getting.

Comment: There is no profile in results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `profile` property in `data` or in the results array. So your assignment `const {profile} = results;` will be undefined

You could point `profile` at the first item in the results array. Then use the property paths for what you want to display

```js
const displayUserPhotoAndName = (data) => {
  if (!data) return;
 
  // add your code here
  const {results} = data;

  const profile = results[0];
  
  const fullName = profile.name.first + ' ' + profile.name.last;

  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = fullName

};

const getAUserProfile = () => {
  const api = 'https://randomuser.me/api/';

  // make API call here
  return fetch(api)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(displayUserPhotoAndName)

};

getAUserProfile()
```

```html
<div id="name"></div>
```

Comment: thanks so much, this worked, i can display the name now but i still get this error     ===>  You have not de-structured the 'profile' property from 'results' obtained from 'data' passed to 'displayUserPhotoAndName' function

Comment: the goal is to de-structures the results variable i created, and obtain the first item from it. the de-structured array item should be declared as profile

Comment: Maybe you are expected to do something like  `const {name:{first,last}} = profile`. Then you can use `first` and `last` as variables

Comment: @ charlietfl the whole thing works well now, but i also need to modify this function below to get and display user's age . this is the function     var displayBirthdate = ({dob}) => {
        const {results} = dob;
      const [profile] = [...results];
        const theage = profile.dob.age;
        document.querySelector('.details').innerHTML = theage + 'years old';
      };

Answer (score 1):

You need this probably:

```
document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = results[0].name.title + results[0].name.first + results[0].name.last;
```

Because the json looks like this:

```
{
  "results":[
    {
      "gender":"male",
      "name":{
        "title":"mr",
        "first":"vidar",
        "last":"sjursen"
      },
      "location":{
        "street":"bestum tverrvei 7385",
        "city":"bratsberg",
        "state":"sogn og fjordane",
        "postcode":"8514",
        "coordinates":{
          "latitude":"57.7278",
          "longitude":"-95.6342"
        },
        "timezone":{
          "offset":"+7:00",
          "description":"Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta"
        }
      },
      "email":"vidar.sjursen@example.com",
      "login":{
        "uuid":"fbc411b4-f34c-497f-acff-8294ddcf8738",
        "username":"whitezebra569",
        "password":"shoes",
        "salt":"8prWID0j",
        "md5":"02ea3e887aaa140ad312905801ae2353",
        "sha1":"c9a66349e68825dc02c74618aac8572fbdd01e5b",
        "sha256":"8297cc85be1127223761fb80b8f554632a6a37c35d58d435293a8f6b2dca19f3"
      },
      "dob":{
        "date":"1952-10-19T01:20:59Z",
        "age":66
      },
      "registered":{
        "date":"2011-11-12T03:06:29Z",
        "age":7
      },
      "phone":"88795425",
      "cell":"92914506",
      "id":{
        "name":"FN",
        "value":"19105218888"
      },
      "picture":{
        "large":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/25.jpg",
        "medium":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/25.jpg",
        "thumbnail":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/25.jpg"
      },
      "nat":"NO"
    }
  ],
  "info":{
    "seed":"48917bf154395ac4",
    "results":1,
    "page":1,
    "version":"1.2"
  }
}
```

Which means, when you do this:

```
const {results} = data;
```

Then the array will be there, and the array doesn't have profile property to get it with:

```
const {profile} = results;
```

Comment: the goal is to de-structures the results variable i created, and obtain the first item from it. the de-structured array item should be declared as profile

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line of code

```
const {results} = data;
-->  const {profile} = results;
```

the "{results}" will take the results property out of your response which in turn is an array.

when you try to take {profile} from results there is no such property like profile in it.

Which makes the profile variable undefined. This was the problem.

**Note: The {something} variable will look for property in your object. [this case the property is something]**

Hope this one helps

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me

```
const displayUserPhotoAndName = (data) => {
            if(!data) return;
            // add your code here
            const {results} = data;
          const [profile] = [...results];

            const fullName = profile.name.title + ' ' + profile.name.last + ' ' + profile.name.first;

      document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = fullName
       document.getElementById('photo').src = profile.picture.large
            displayExtraUserInfo(profile);

            clearNotice();
          };
```

Answer (score -1):

`const {profile} = results;` here `profile` is `undefined` because `results` is an array with no property profile.

You need to do `const profile = [...results];` and then `document.getElementById('name').innerHTML =  profile[0].name.title + profile[0].name.first + profile[0].name.last;`

```js
fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
      if (!data) return;
      const {
        results
      } = data;
      const profile = [...results];
      console.log(profile)
      document.getElementById('name').innerHTML =  profile[0].name.title + profile[0].name.first + profile[0].name.last;
    }

  )
```

```html
<div id="name"></div>
```

Comment: @downoters can you specify what is wrong in this answer?